# How to use javascript to add #new after all links

Tags: javascript

I have the following code and I want all the links in the ul to be added #new by javascript , Can you help me?

```
<ul id="ul-data">
    <li class="data">
        <a href="/3/">data 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="data">
        <a href="/2/">data 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="data">
     <a href="/1/">data 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="data">
     <a href="/0/">data 0</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I haven't found a solution yet

Comment: please share with us what you have tried/ where you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the elements using the same syntax as css selectors, then you can loop over each selected element and replace the href attribute. The final result would look something like this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#ul-data .data a').forEach((el) => {
    el.href = el.href + "#new";
});
```

note that the space is needed in the selector to select the elements inside another element

Comment: thank you for the feedback, i tried it but it didn't work

Comment: saying it doesn't work doesn't help me either. You need to give more detail surrounding your questions and this answer.

Comment: edited my answer. Tip: don't copy paste code without at least trying to look at what it's doing. If you'd taken the time to understand what it's doing and noticed I did not include selecting the a tag you would've been done now.

Comment: I want after loading page automatically add #new after link in the above ul

I have researched and don't understand how it works,
Please help me, complete code.

Comment: the code should already work, did you try the edited code?

Comment: please let me know if it worked and if so mark this as an answer. Leaving the question open leads me to believe you're still working on it